# Aurelia official contact list tutorial fails to render after adding Bootstrap configurations

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, aurelia

I'm following the official Aurelia tutorial to build a contact list app.

I'm stuck at "Building Out The Default Route" step and I start to get really pissed off.

I added the vendor dependencies for bootstrap and jquery as shown in the tutorial, but when i launch the page, renders blank and console outputs several errors:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: h.load is not a function

   Unhandled rejection Error: Failed loading required CSS file: ../node_modules/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
at fixupCSSUrls (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:23357:13)
at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:23396:16
```

now, i googled **a lot**, found several users having the same problem, but every fix didn't work. I tried several fix, checking for typos and errors (i'm just halfway of the tutorial, how many typing mistakes may i have done???), restart `au run --watch`, even copy paste the code directly from the tutorial page (i hate to do this because doesn't help my learning, but i was desperate). Nothing, the exact same errors continue to fire up and the page is still blank. I'm really freaking out about this apparently small stupid issues like completing an official tutorial.

Complete source [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B80P5wPtzz3OX2Z2eWVWZWtyenc) I included ALL files on purpose, to show you exactly how my sourcebase looks like.

`aurelia.json`

```
{
  "name": "Contact Manager",
  "type": "project:application",
  "platform": {
    "id": "web",
    "displayName": "Web",
    "output": "scripts"
  },
  "transpiler": {
    "id": "babel",
    "displayName": "Babel",
    "fileExtension": ".js",
    "options": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-modules-amd"
      ]
    },
    "source": "src/**/*.js"
  },
  "markupProcessor": {
    "id": "none",
    "displayName": "None",
    "fileExtension": ".html",
    "source": "src/**/*.html"
  },
  "cssProcessor": {
    "id": "none",
    "displayName": "None",
    "fileExtension": ".css",
    "source": "src/**/*.css"
  },
  "editor": {
    "id": "vscode",
    "displayName": "Visual Studio Code"
  },
  "unitTestRunner": {
    "id": "karma",
    "displayName": "Karma",
    "source": "test/unit/**/*.js"
  },
  "paths": {
    "root": "src",
    "resources": "src/resources",
    "elements": "src/resources/elements",
    "attributes": "src/resources/attributes",
    "valueConverters": "src/resources/value-converters",
    "bindingBehaviors": "src/resources/binding-behaviors"
  },
  "testFramework": {
    "id": "jasmine",
    "displayName": "Jasmine"
  },
  "build": {
    "targets": [
      {
        "id": "web",
        "displayName": "Web",
        "output": "scripts"
      }
    ],
    "loader": {
      "type": "require",
      "configTarget": "vendor-bundle.js",
      "includeBundleMetadataInConfig": "auto",
      "plugins": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "extensions": [
            ".html",
            ".css"
          ],
          "stub": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "options": {
      "minify": "stage & prod",
      "sourcemaps": "dev & stage"
    },
    "bundles": [
      {
        "name": "app-bundle.js",
        "source": [
          "[**/*.js]",
          "**/*.{css,html}"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "vendor-bundle.js",
        "prepend": [
          "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.core.js",
          "scripts/require.js"
        ],
        "dependencies": [
          "aurelia-binding",
          "aurelia-bootstrapper",
          "aurelia-dependency-injection",
          "aurelia-event-aggregator",
          "aurelia-framework",
          "aurelia-history",
          "aurelia-history-browser",
          "aurelia-loader",
          "aurelia-loader-default",
          "aurelia-logging",
          "aurelia-logging-console",
          "aurelia-metadata",
          "aurelia-pal",
          "aurelia-pal-browser",
          "aurelia-path",
          "aurelia-polyfills",
          "aurelia-route-recognizer",
          "aurelia-router",
          "aurelia-task-queue",
          "aurelia-templating",
          "aurelia-templating-binding",
          {
            "name": "text",
            "path": "../scripts/text"
          },
          {
            "name": "aurelia-templating-resources",
            "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-templating-resources/dist/amd",
            "main": "aurelia-templating-resources"
          },
          {
            "name": "aurelia-templating-router",
            "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-templating-router/dist/amd",
            "main": "aurelia-templating-router"
          },
          {
            "name": "aurelia-testing",
            "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-testing/dist/amd",
            "main": "aurelia-testing",
            "env": "dev"
          },
          "jquery",
          {
            "name": "bootstrap",
            "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
            "main": "js/bootstrap",
            "deps": ["jquery"],
            "exports": "$",
            "resources": [
              "css/bootstrap.css"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`app.js`

```
import { Router, RouterConfiguration} from 'aurelia-router';

export class App {
  router: Router;

  configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
    config.title = 'Contacts';
    config.map([
      { route: '', moduleId: 'no-selection', title: 'Select' },
      { route: 'contact/:id', muduleId: 'contact-detail', name:'contacts' }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
  }
}
```

and `app.html`

```
<template>
  <require from="../node_modules/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
  <require from="./styles.css"></require>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        <span>Contacts</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        Contact List Placeholder
      </div>

      <router-view class="col-md-8"></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<require from="../node_modules/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>`

needs to be

`<require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>`

You've also mispelled `moduleId` in the `contacts` route in `app.js`. You've got `muduleId`.

Comment: This only changes the second error message to `Unhandled rejection Error: Failed loading required CSS file: bootstrap/css/boostrap.css` :-)

Comment: I made the two changes I showed and your code loaded fine.

Comment: It's actually the correct solution, because like the OP I had a typo in my require directive as well! The `h.load` error is not critical.

Comment: @AshleyGrant thank you very much for your help. Your answer fixed a part of the problem, i mean, i still get errors about jQuery, but the page renders as expected at the moment. Your Answer did really help, I'm new in posting on SO, I have to mark your question as the correct one or leave it neutral till we solve the jquery issues?

Comment: @mhutter thank you for your feedback too. You didn't get the jQuery errors like me, after the changes?

Comment: @FrancescoPaoletti I still get the `h.load is not a function` message, but the app works!

Comment: @mhutter weird thing is, after the changes i don't get the `h.load is not a function` message anymore...

Comment: @mhutter i updated aurelia-cli to 0.19.0 as @AshleyGrant suggested in the comments below and everything worked with no errors. Try updating it, i believe you should get rid of `h.load is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Well, believe me, better you're not here, you'd get scared from my curses even if is italian...
I really don't know how is it possible, i checked everything multiple times even after i started over again and rewrote the entire damn thing....

Anyway, first of all thank you. I feel like a moron.

I fixed the typo for module and changed the `require` statement as suggested. Now the page renders as expected, but console still shows me an error stating that bootstrap needs Jquery. I already installed jQuery via npm, so, i'm puzzled...

here is a [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/p3w7I)

I also tried adding

```
<require from="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></require>
```

but doesn't work.

Any ideas?

and why i had to remove "../node_modules/" from the `require` statement? It doesn't load bootstrap from the node_module dir?

Comment: Stop adding `node_modules` in the require from path. That was part of your original issue, but you're doing it again here.

Comment: Actually. Sorry, you don't load JavaScript using require elements. You load JavaScript using `import` statements in your JavaScript files. I'd recommend re-reading the tutorial before moving on.

Comment: You don't put node_modules in the path bc you taught the loader (in `aurelia.json`) that when it sees `bootstrap\...`  it should load stuff from `node_modules\bootstrap\...`.

Comment: @AshleyGrant thank you for your patience and your kind explaination. So I need to add ` import "jquery" ` in main.js to load it properly and avoid the error in the screenshot? jquery is already listed as a dependecy in `aurelia.js`

Comment: You shouldn't need to add that. Please make sure you have the latest version of the Aurelia CLI. If you run `au -v` you should see `0.19.0` or higher.

Comment: My Aurelia CLI version is 0.18.0, actually...updating the CLI should ifx the error?

Comment: It might, but since the CLI is alpha software, you should definitely make sure you have the latest version, as bugfixes and new features are in every version.

Comment: @AshleyGrant thank you very much. I updated aurelia-cli to 0.19.0 and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

`aurelia.json` file is actually a `require.js` config file. Those two information should be enough to know what documentation to look at but basically, a `require.js` dependency like this one:

```
{
  "name": "bootstrap",
  "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
  "main": "js/bootstrap.min",
  "deps": [
    "jquery"
  ],
  "resources": [
    "css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ]
}
```

works like this: resources are `require'd` as module name + resource (resource needs extensions defined!), ie. `<require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"></require>` while javascript files are required by `<require from="bootstrap"></require>`, ie. just the module name to require the `main` file defined above, or `<require from="bootstrap/some_path_to_jsfile_without_ext"></require>`, ie. the module name + relative path to file to require some file relative to the `path` defined above.

**DISCLAIMER** : I'm a new web developer and have just started with Aurelia.